# Java and Google Calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-data

I would be shocked if this were immediately answered here, as this is a question specific to the Google Calendar Java API, but I'll put it out there anyway.

The tutorials for Google Calendar give a nice explanation of [Calendar Insertion](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingCalendars) as well as [Event Insertion](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingSingle).  However, I would really like to create a calendar on my server, add events to it, and then insert the whole mess into my user's Google Calendar.  Is this possible?

Here is the api for [CalendarEntry](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/calendar/CalendarEntry.html)...  `addExtension()` looks suspicious, but I'm clueless as to whether or not it does anything in Google Calendar.

Also, I am aware of the alternative solution to this:

- Create the calendar
- Insert the calendar
- Create the events
- Insert the events

...But this way is rather ugly.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to read the section about batch requests

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers%5Fguide%5Fjava.html#batch

I don't think there's an API for uploading an entire calendar full of events in one operation, your best bet is to do it in one or more batches.  From the docs:

> the size of the request must be under
>   a megabyte and it's best to limit
>   batches to 50-100 operations at a time